# email link embedded in a clickable line item

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a line item that when clicked will call a function that directs me to another page, but in the line item is an email address link.  But when i click on the email link it will redirect me as if i had clicked on any other part of the line item.  How can i change this so the email link will bring up the email client but the rest of the line item will redirect?

```
<li data-bind="click: $parent.UserInfo">
    <table>
        <tr class="colleague">
            <td>
                <img src="./images/default.gif"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table width="100%">                            
                <tr><td><span class="firstname_" data-bind="text: firstname"></span>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: lastname"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a data-bind="text: email, attr: { href: 'mailto:'+email} "></a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span data-bind="text: phone"></span></td></tr>
                <tr><td><span>Location: </span><span data-bind="text: location"></span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two concepts that Knockout provides that can help you on this one.

If you have an `click` (or a specific event through `event` binding), then you can include an additional option with the event name followed by `Bubble` and set it to false.  So, you can do:

```
data-bind="click: someAction, clickBubble: false"
```

Second, if you return `true` from the handler called from the `click` binding (or `event` binding), then it will allow the default action to proceed.

So, one option would be to add a `click` binding with a function that returns `true` to your inner link and then also add a `clickBubble: false`.  So, something like:

```
<td><a data-bind="text: email, attr: { href: 'mailto:'+email}, click: alwaysTrue, clickBubble: false"></a></td>
```

This assumes that you have an `alwaysTrue` function that returns `true`.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UDHAp/

To simplify you could even write a custom binding to do this for you.  Here is a sample that would wrap the click binding (choose a short name, if you like):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.preventBubbleButAllowDefaultAction = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: function() { return true; }, clickBubble: false });
        }

    }        
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gyJsd/

or slightly more efficient to do what we want without wrapping the existing bindings:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.preventBubbleButAllowDefaultAction = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())) {
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function() {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
                if (event.stopPropagation) {
                    event.stopPropagation(); 
                }              
            });
        }  
    }        
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gyJsd/2/